# Converting string to datetime format shows yyyy/dd/mm for first 12 rows and yyyy/mm/dd for remaining rows for each month

Tags: datetime-format, date-formatting

Problem: I imported a csv from google drive, selected few columns, applied ''date format'' to 'Date' column and then tried to filter a particular month.

**Edit**

I'm using Python as programming language.

This is my code I used:

```
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
import gspread
from google.auth import default
creds, _ = default()
gc = gspread.authorize(creds)
worksheet = gc.open('Sale_Data_WC_2022').sheet1
# get_all_values gives a list of rows.
rows = worksheet.get_all_values()
print(rows)
# Convert to a DataFrame and render.
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(rows)
df1 = df.iloc[:,[1,2,5,6,7,8,9]]
df1 = df1.rename(columns={df1.columns[0]: 'Date'})
df1
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'])
df1
```

Output:

```
01-01-22 0:00
01-02-22 0:00
01-03-22 0:00
01-04-22 0:00
01-05-22 0:00
01-06-22 0:00
01-07-22 0:00
01-08-22 0:00
01-10-22 0:00
01-11-22 0:00
01-12-22 0:00
13-01-22 0:00
14-01-22 0:00
15-01-22 0:00
17-01-22 0:00
18-01-22 0:00
19-01-22 0:00
20-01-22 0:00
21-01-22 0:00
22-01-22 0:00
24-01-22 0:00
25-01-22 0:00
26-01-22 0:00
27-01-22 0:00
```

Format shows `yyyy-dd-mm` for first 12 rows and `yyyy-mm-dd` for remaining rows for each month.

Comment: Need to see your code and sample of your data please also tag the programming language you are using.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Which programming language and which date library is that? I’m afraid that no one can answer as the question stands at the moment, so please edit.

Comment: What were your original strings? I suspect that they were interpreted wrong.

Comment: take a counter and inside loop format yyyy/dd/mm when counter <= 12 and for others make format as yyyy/mm/dd. hope you get my point.